# Identity Framework User Lockdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to lock user login after 3 unsuccessful login attempts for 5 minutes. I have add this 3 lines to `App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs` `public static ApplicationUserManager Create( ... )` method:

```
manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 3;
manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
```

After that I register new user via `POST /api/Account/Register` (in default scaffolded `AccountController`). Account is created and `LockoutEnabled` property is set to `true`. But if I try to login for via `POST /Token` few times with wrong password account isn't locked down.

I'm also interested where is implementation of `/Token` endpoint. Is it in `AccountController` `GET api/Account/ExternalLogin`. I have set breakpoint there but execution wasn't stopped there when I tried to login.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the default Web API template from Visual Studio, you have to change the behavior of `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method of the `ApplicationOAuthProvider` class (found inside the Provider folder of your Web API project). Something like this could allow you to track failed login attempts, and stop locked out users from logging in:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

    var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);

    if (user == null)
    { 
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Wrong username or password."); //user not found
        return;
    }

    if (await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
    {
        context.SetError("locked_out", "User is locked out");
        return;
    }

    var check = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, context.Password);

    if (!check)
    {
        await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Wrong username or password."); //wrong password
        return;
    }

    await userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);

    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
       OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
    context.Validated(ticket);
    context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
}
```

Be aware that this way you can only lock out users trying to login using the `password` grant (Resource Owner Credentials). If you also want to disallow locked out user to login using other grants, you have to override the other methods (`GrantAuthorizationCode`, `GrantRefreshToken`, etc.), checking if `await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id)` is true in those methods too.

Comment: You are welcome. I just edited the answer, I was forgetting to reset the failed access count after the user successfully signs in.