# Lock ASP.NET login user for X minutes after Y invalid attempts and userManager.IsLockedOutAsync is false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I am working on asp.net web api project and trying to implement the functionality that would lock the user login for X minutes after Y invalid attempts.

I have set this in Identity Config

```
        // Enable Lock outs
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 1;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
```

In **IdentityConfig.cs**

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true,
             
        };
        // Enable Lock outs

        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 1;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        manager.EmailService = new EmailServiceCustom();
        int Token = 24;
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenLifespan"] != null
         )
        {
            Token = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenLifespan"]);
        }

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
            {
                TokenLifespan = System.TimeSpan.FromHours(Token)
            };
        }
        return manager;
    }
```

and in **OAuthProvider.cs** Class

```
   public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            //context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();


            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName).ConfigureAwait(false);

            //var user= await context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
            //    .FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
            
            if (await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
            {
                context.SetError("locked_out", "User is locked out");
                return;
            }

            if (!await userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "You need to confirm your email.");
                return;
            }

            var check = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, context.Password);

            if (!check)
            {
                await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The password is incorrect."); //wrong password
                return;
            }
            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await (await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password).ConfigureAwait(false)).GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT").ConfigureAwait(false);
            
            var userForCheck = this.userService.GetUserById((await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password).ConfigureAwait(false)).Id);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket;

            if ((oAuthIdentity.IsAuthenticated && userForCheck == null) ||
                oAuthIdentity.IsAuthenticated && userForCheck.status)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>();

                var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync((await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password).ConfigureAwait(false)).Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
                claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim("role", role)));

                claims.Add(new Claim("unique_name", (await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password).ConfigureAwait(false)).UserName));
                claims.Add(new Claim("email", (await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password).ConfigureAwait(false)).Email));

                oAuthIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
                ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);
                context.Validated(ticket);
            }
        }
```

but **user.LockoutEnabled** is false and `userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id)` is also returning false even after invalid attempt. What am i am doing wrong here?

I took help of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447153/identity-framework-user-lockdown) but still same issue

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447153/identity-framework-user-lockdown

Comment: @greg it didn't work. i have updated the code above

Comment: The only difference I can see is var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName).ConfigureAwait(false); should be without ConfigureAwait var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName); . Can you run a break point and confirm if this line gets called "await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id)"?

Comment: I removed ConfigureAwait and when password is wrong it calls userManager.AccessFailedAsync .But when i try to login next time with correct password, i am able to login.i see property LockOutEnable is false although lockoutenddateutc have some value.i have set manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 1;

Comment: After you call GetUserManager. Can you add 2 lines: var dateWhenUserIsNotLoggedOut = await userManager.GetLockoutEndDateAsync(user.Id); & var isLockedOutPossibleForUser = await userManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id); and then call it again after AccessFailedAsync(). The first one should have the UTC time of when the user is locked out. I believe the second one should always be true.

Comment: userManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id) is false in both case

Comment: that suggests that the lockout functionality is not enabled for the user and therefore ignores the locking out on accessFail(). To  test this theory can you add "await userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id, true);" - you could hardocde it, run it and then test the code with removed?

Comment: Now it worked  await userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id, true);

                await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
                 dateWhenUserIsNotLoggedOut = await userManager.GetLockoutEndDateAsync(user.Id);
                isLockedOutPossibleForUser = await userManager.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id);

Comment: I'm guessing here, but you've created the user after you've created the lockout functionality. Therefore default is false and the property UserLockoutEnabledByDefault is ignored. You might want to create another user to check the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this issue:

If you've created a user before implementing the lockout functionality `UserLockoutEnabledByDefault` will be ignored. This is because default only apply when the value (*UserLockOut*) is null. However this property is set to false.

Therefore you'll need to do a one time change to set lockout to true (for existing users only). `e.g await userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id, true);`